# Get index of data binding from ItemsControl

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

Is there any way to get the index of the data which is binded to the ItemsControl, when a button is clicked?

```
<ItemsControl  x:Name="ic_schranke" DataContext="{Binding Schranke}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >

                        <Button Height="80" x:Name="btn_open" Click="btn_open_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource TransparentStyle}">
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Opacity="0.65" Grid.Column="0" Fill="#FFCEEAFF"/>

                                <Border CornerRadius="25" Height="50" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/schranken.jpg" />
                                    </Border.Background>
                                </Border>

                                <TextBlock Name="schranken_name" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="ExtraLight" Foreground="Black" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Button>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Here is the sample data which is binded to the IC:

```
 List<Schranke> elements;
        public UserPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            elements = new List<Schranke>();
            for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++)
                elements.Add(new Schranke() { name = $"Schranke NR:{i}" });


            this.ic_schranke.ItemsSource = elements;


}
```

And here is the code in the button click event:

```
private async void btn_open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Grid grid = (sender as Button).Content as Grid;



            //Debug.WriteLine($"content {tb.Text} clicked");
            var tmp_background = grid.Background;
            grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(new Windows.UI.Color() { A = 255, R = 78, G = 170, B = 44 });
            VibrationDevice testVibrationDevice = VibrationDevice.GetDefault();
            testVibrationDevice.Vibrate(System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150));
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            grid.Background = tmp_background;
        }
```

Comment: Why not use a command instead of an event (better practice), and send in the command parameter the object in the list? or at least it's ID.
I can't exactly give a sample code without the definition of Schranke

Comment: Schranke is a class with string name as only member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something along the lines of this:

the presenter - put this in the data context

```
public class SchrankePresenter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Schranke> _elements;
    public List<Schranke> Elements
    {
        get { return _elements; }
        set
        {
            _elements = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Elements");
        }
    }
    public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public SchrankePresenter()
    {
        var elements = new List<Schranke>();
        for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++)
            elements.Add(new Schranke() { Name = $"Schranke NR:{i}" });

        Elements = elements;
        ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(ClickAction);
    }

    public void ClickAction(Schranke item)
    {
        VibrationDevice.GetDefault().Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150));
    }
}

public class Schranke
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

the template:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

                    <Button Height="80"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                            Style="{StaticResource TransparentStyle}">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="30*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Rectangle x:Name="rect"
                                       Grid.Row="1"
                                       Grid.Column="0"
                                       Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                       Fill="#FFCEEAFF"
                                       Opacity="0.65" />

                            <Border Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Width="50"
                                    Height="50"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    CornerRadius="25">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/schranken.jpg" />
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>

                            <TextBlock Name="schranken_name"
                                       Grid.Row="1"
                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       FontWeight="ExtraLight"
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>

                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
```

you can do the background animation using a storyboard/visualstate

**EDIT** : regarding the DelegateCommand, it's a simple implementation I use for my WPF apps -

```
internal class DelegateCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private Action<T> _clickAction;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> clickAction)
    {
        _clickAction = clickAction;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _clickAction((T)parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I get your idea to solve my problem, but I don't get whats to do with  the DelegateCommand(ClickAction). Can you explain this part?

Comment: I've added an explanation in the original response, it's a quick and basic implementation for ICommand, Use whatever fits your needs. This usually fits mine.

Comment: After adding the class to the project I'm getting this error code "Using the generic type 'DelegateCommand<T>' requires '1' type arguments". I have a feeling that you know the issue and know to fix it.

Comment: haha yes, change this:
ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(ClickAction);
into this:
ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand<Schranke>(ClickAction);

Comment: another question: you said I should put the presenter in the data context. Which data context did you mean? I put this lines into the page constructor : `presenter = new SchrankePresenter();
            this.lv_schranken.DataContext = presenter;`
where presenter is a member var of the Page and lv_schranken the name of the Listview is.

Comment: no reason to keep the presenter as a member of any class, you shouldn't need to reference it directly externally at any point. just create one and put it in the page's data context in the page's CTOR.
That way the ListView will reference the 'elements' property for data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118143/discussion-between-student96-and-michaelthepotato).